# Windows-10 IoT-core ARM DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

Unable to deploy uwp app on RPi ARM device. Before Visual Studio Update 2 I had no problems deploying to these devices (LAN, not USB). I get this error:

DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906

I currently have Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2

Based on some suggestion on the internet, I tried deleting any previously installed version of my app on device before re-installing, but I still see the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, what it took:

- Re-install the IoT-Core OS on the ARM/RPi from scratch.
- Reboot the windows 10 dev computer
- Clean and rebuild the project.

Error gone.